# I'm a little [puzzle]d as to why we even have this tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/puzzle) tag has the following description:

> DO NOT USE - prefer constructive questions, or use more descriptive tags. Otherwise, your question might be appropriate for codegolf.stackexchange.com.

This is an obvious Meta-tag - it doesn't describe the actual topic of the question in the least, just what kind of question it is.

This is also ambiguous - it sometimes refers to literal puzzles (e.g. jigsaw puzzles), to coding puzzles, or to something that the OP is merely puzzled or confused about.

This does not mean the same thing in all common contexts.

Also, even the tag description admits that questions in this tag may not even be on topic - questions like this should often be on Code Golf SE instead.

Can we burninate this?