# Some [puzzle]-ing tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I ran across someone trying to [create an excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25674030) for the new tag [15-puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/15-puzzle). The excerpt screamed "meta tag"

> The 15-puzzle is a 4x4 sliding puzzle

I found the only question with that tag is also tagged [8-puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/8-puzzle) (137 questions) which doesn't look much better

> The 8-puzzle is a 3x3 sliding puzzle that consists of a frame of numbered square tiles in random order with one tile missing.

There's a whole host of them, in fact

- [zebra-puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zebra-puzzle) - 86 questions
- [cryptarithmetic-puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cryptarithmetic-puzzle) - 55 questions
- [river-crossing-puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/river-crossing-puzzle) - 36 questions
- [eight-peg-puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eight-peg-puzzle) - 1 question
- [puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/puzzle) - 755 questions with a "DO NOT USE" excerpt

Are tags about puzzles appropriate here? Do we need any of these lesser tags? While they might describe the puzzle, they don't necessarily help people find questions (the low usage numbers bear that out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tags about a specific puzzle** don't seem like "meta" tags to me. They describe the content of the question itself. Solving one type of puzzle is a very different programming problem than solving another type of puzzle, just like writing a Windows GUI program is a very different exercise than writing a Windows console application.

This is precedent already established by [a declined burninate request for the [sudoku] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273080/should-we-burn-sudoku), which is another very specific type of puzzle.

<strike>Now, it may be that the 8-puzzle is essentially the same as the 15-puzzle, and those two tags should be merged. Is there perhaps a more general name for this type of puzzle that could be used as the "master" tag?</strike>

Since the 8-puzzle and 15-puzzle are specific cases of the [sliding puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle), I agree that these are duplicate tags in need of a merge. In order to avoid the ambiguity with a "slider" UI widget noted by 1201ProgramAlarm, I created [sliding-tile-puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sliding-tile-puzzle) as the master tag, and then made the various tags synonyms of that one. I also wrote a tag wiki.

I do agree, of course, that the [puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/puzzle) tag is a useless "meta" tag—who cares that you're solving *a* puzzle? Aren't we *always* solving puzzles? But that's [a different burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389389/im-a-little-puzzled-as-to-why-we-even-have-this-tag).

Comment: Just to supplement this answer, questions about software algorithms are explicitly on topic, so a language-agnostic (like an implementation pseudo code) question about part of an algorithm to solve, say, an 8-peg-puzzle, wouldn't have a tag more appropriate than 8-peg-puzzle because an expert on that algorithm would use that to find it.

Comment: Both the 8-puzzle and 15-puzzle are types of slider puzzles (although I think of them as 9 and 16 rather than 8 and 15).  So a generic "slider-puzzle" could cover both, but could also be potentially confused with the UI [tag:slider] widget.

Comment: Looks like this is actually called [a "sliding puzzle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle). I'm going to go with "sliding-tile-puzzle" to hopefully avoid the ambiguity with various UI widgets that @1201ProgramAlarm pointed out.

Comment: That will work for me. I had forgotten about sudoku, which reminded me about [flappy-bird-clone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273079/we-have-a-flappy-bird-clone-tag-really)

Answer (score 5):

My opinion is they are not necessary. They describe the type of problem being solved rather than the type of technology being used. Having said that, I also do not think they are harmful in any way. I had a quick scan through those tags and they don't attract off-topic or low quality answers by and large.

We could edit them out of all these questions to not give anyone ideas to create more like these, but I don't see any major benefit in doing so. [eight-peg-puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eight-peg-puzzle) could be simply sent to roomba once the question gets retagged.

In some cases, if we were to edit the tag out, the only tag left would be [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) or [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic). Having an additional tag describing what kind of algorithm is sought could actually be useful.

My opinion: don't waste time with it now.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want a full burn like [puzzle] just yet, but some of the tertiary tags could easily go